# Как правильно записать название вывески?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, раздельно-дефис

Из художественной литературы:

*Над входом он увидел большую вывеску **ЦИРКЪ-ШАПИТО.***

Это дореформенная запись. Как сейчас правильно записать название на вывеске, используя **прописные и строчные буквы?**

Или (при затруднении) лучше оставить **все прописные?**

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ВОПРОС**

Решить задачу действительно сложно. Сочетание в словаре РАН пишется так: **цирк шапито**.  Тогда на вывеске придется писать: **Цирк шапито**. Из комментария: *Но в названии это выглядит странно. Шапито – важная характеристика, это самостоятельное слово по словарю, а у нас что получается. В таком сочетании цирк скорее является родовым словом (приложением).*

Но как же решить задачу, чтобы все **правила** соблюсти и выбрать походящую **графику** для вывески. У меня появилась идея, но мне бы хотелось услышать **ваши предложения.**

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150669/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: 8. пишется раздельно в составе сочетания существительного с постпозитивным несклоняемым приложением  (рукав реглан, па шассе, птица феникс, ***цирк шапито,*** кофе глясе)

Comment: Что касается самой вывески, то в статье все прекрасно описано.

Comment: @Серж  Кто бы спорил? Есть нарицательное сочетание "цирк шапито", где шапито является приложением. Цирк шатровый – так в вывеске напишем? Я пишу:  Цирк ШАТРО. Вывеска – это самостоятельное название, которое выбирает хозяин цирка.  Вы можете уличить его в нарушении правил? Или вы хотите, чтобы он в вывеске обозначил, что шапито – это приложение.

Comment: А зачем уличать его   в нарушении правил? У него все верно.

Answer (score 1):

• Вспомним, что говорится в правилах мэтра Розенталя ([§ 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154#pp154)).

> **Примечание.** Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится...
>
> Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова *предложение, выражение, надпись* и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие:
> *Над воротами возвысилась вывеска, изображающая дородного амура с опрокинутым факелом в руке, с подписью: **«Здесь продаются и обиваются гробы простые и крашеные…»*** (П.)...

• Посмотрим, что имеется в художественной литературе (1. О. Рой. Е. Неволина. Цирк кошмаров. 2. И. Рэнкин. Плоть и кровь).

1. > Сейчас на ней были припаркованы два здоровенных трейлера, на чьих металлических корпусах красовались цирковые эмблемы, не слишком умело нарисованные рожи клоунов и сделанная веселенькими разноцветными красками надпись: «ЦИРК ШАПИТО».
   > — «Шапито» — это название цирка? — поинтересовалась Алиса.
   > — Это общее название таких походных цирков с шатром, который можно собрать и разобрать. Все бродячие цирки называются шапито, — ответил Олег, даже не задумавшись.
2. > Чтобы попасть туда, нужно было пройти мимо ряда деревянных ящиков с надписью «Заморозку — сюда!».

• Даже у классиков, С. Маршака и С. Михалкова, наблюдаются "разнонаписания".

*Пред вами — вы знаете что?

Игрушечный цирк Шапито.* [цирк шапито]

*— Это что?

— Это цирк Шапито!* [Цирк Шапито, ЦИРК ШАПИТО, цирк ШАПИТО]

• Интереснейший вопрос — три в одном.

Я бы написала так:
**Над входом он увидел большую вывеску: «Цирк шапито».**
(*И тут я увидел вывеску: «Белый медведь»* (Юрий Коваль. На барсучьих правах)).

Или так (чтобы показать, что буквы одинаковые, крупные):
**Над входом он увидел большую вывеску: ЦИРК ШАПИТО.**
(*Когда зажглись фонари, Сапожков вернулся и увидел вывеску: КАССА* (Юрий Петкевич. Явление ангела)).

P. S. [Цирк шапито](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=71) (Русский орфографический словарь)
Удивительно, но в орфографическом словаре 1957 года С. И. Ожегова и А. Б. Шапиро (110 тысяч слов) нет ни слова "шапито", ни сочетания "цирк шапито".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, там много полезных сведений по теме. Голос от меня. Чуть позже я дам свой вариант ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Выбираем **два варианта** оформления:

*Над входом он увидел большую вывеску **ЦИРК ШАПИТО.***

*Над входом он увидел большую вывеску: **Цирк Шапито.***

**В чем же моя идея?**

1. Это предложение оформлено не правилу Розенталя  **для цитирования,** а особым образом. **Это БСП**, где вторая часть — это **сама вывеска, как мы ее видим**. Поэтому нет там кавычек, а отношение между частями БСП пояснительные (обозначены двоеточием).
2. Я использую **две прописные буквы.** Можно ли так делать? Да, вполне. Это означает, что имя собственное состоит **из двух равноправных слов.** Иначе говоря, **нарицательное** сочетание «цирк шапито» мы записываем как **имя собственное** «Цирк Шапито». В ПАС обозначена **выделительная** функция прописных букв, и в данном случае можно выделить **оба слова**.

Если мы напишем ***Цирк шапито***, то **шапито** будет нарицательным существительным, но ведь это **не менее важная** часть названия, чем цирк. Я могла бы написать только *Шапито* (= шатровый цирк), в словаре есть такое значение.

**ШАПИТО**, неизм.; ср. [франц. chapiteau]. Большая передвижная, обычно брезентовая палатка для цирковых представлений, **передвижной цирк**, дающий представления в такой палатке. Разбить ш. на площади. [] в функц. опр. Цирк-шапито.

**Примечание.** Интересно, что дефисное написание в словаре Кузнецова тоже дается, но для вывески он вряд ли подойдет. К тому же раздельный вариант указан в словаре РАН.

Comment: @Серж, я про второй вариант спрашиваю. Как бы вы написали, если бы не было у вас возможности использовать только прописные буквы. Не завезли, например...)   И это не мои выдумки и фантазии,  Это серьезное обсуждение ТЕМЫ "Прописные и строчные буквы в именах собственных".  А именно как автор выбирает название, насколько он свободен в этом выборе. Ведь не секрет, что во многих составных именах не только первое слово пишется с прописной буквы.  А мы в ответах ПЕРЕМЕШАЛИ две темы: оформление цитирования в вывесках и выбор самого названия на этих вывесках. Вам это не кажется?

Comment: А автор должен выбирать в соответствии с устоявшийся традицией.

Comment: @Серж, устоявшаяся традиция – это что? Нечто неопределенное, то, что каждый понимает по-своему? Я полагаю, что автор в своих названиях свободен настолько, насколько ему позволяют правила русского письма. Надо всего лишь внимательно отнестись к этой теме. А я этой внимательности не вижу. Достаточно вспомнить названия спортивных команд, которые здесь обсуждались, а также названия года по восточному календарю.  Надо различать собственные и нарицательные названия в составных именах, а это не так просто, как кажется.

Comment: Кстати, о традиции.  "Пред вами — вы знаете что? Игрушечный цирк Шапито".  Здесь выделено прописными буквами слово "Шапито".  Как вам такая традиция?

Comment: Не вижу причин в данном случае писать "шапито" прописными. Что касается названия года, то там не было спорных моментов.

Comment: Ладно,завтра постараюсь написать свой ответ. Просто я сейчас с телефона пишу, тяжело писать развернутый ответ.

Comment: Серж, спасибо за участие в теме, но вы уходите от ответа.  Если напишете, то спасибо.  А в названиях года были варианты: год кролика или год Кролика.  Их надо было сравнить.  Мы часто не замечаем очевидные вещи)

Comment: Год Кролика. Как название года.

Comment: Я вам уже ответил. Традиция оформления вывесок.

Comment: Да, но в самом вопросе были предложены два варианта. Никто даже и не подумал их сравнить.  Ладно, Серж, еще раз спасибо, но традиция меня не устраивает. Я вам привела пример другой традиции: Игрушечный цирк Шапито".  Писать строчную букву на вывеске попросту некрасиво.

Comment: Что здесь шапито — имя собственное или нарицательное... Вот и решение... Кажется нарицательное.

Comment: Мы говорим с вами на разных языках, нет смысла продолжать)

Comment: Почему назвали Северный Ледовитый океан? Там действительно много льда,  это нарицательное слово с реальным значением. А у них оно входит в название и пишется с прописной. Непорядок!